# Esconder div con JQUERY da problemas si display se declara mediante bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

quizá sea lo más fácil del mundo pero no doy con la clave. Estoy empezando con JQUERY y hay cosas que no pillo.
 Tengo un div con #comentarios y quiero que al hacer click en un boton desaparezca/aparezca. Si quiero cambiar cualquier propiedad css no tengo problema, pero al usar .hide() o .css('display','none') no funciona.
 Imaginemos que este es div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cambiar').on("click",function(){
        $('#comentarios').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="cambiar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-5 text-uppercase float-left">comentarios</button>
<div id="comentarios" class="comentarios row col-12 d-flex flex-row align-items-center">

            <div class="comentario row col-12">
                <div class="asociado col-3">
                    <img src="img/avatares/carnetbyw.jpg" alt="" class="col-10 rounded-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="comentario row col-12">
                <div class="asociado col-3">
                    <img src="img/avatares/carnetbyw.jpg" alt="" class="col-10 rounded-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Usa `$('#comentarios').slideToggle();` que hace animación!

Comment: Lo que dice Roy debería funcionar. Solo agregar que, en mi caso particular, siempre he trabajado con Hide() y Show() en JQuery a la de ocultar o mostrar objetos de formularios, nunca con DIV; por ejemplo $("#txtEjemplo").Show(); / $("#txtEjemplo").Hide();

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos. Acabo de comprobar que lo que me impide cambiar el display o ejecutar .hide() es el hecho de tener esa clase para bootstrap `comentarios row col-12 d-flex flex-row align-items-center` ¿Es normal esto?

Comment: Efectivamente, lo que te está provocando la imposibilidad de poder ocultar el elemento es la clase `.d-flex`. Inspeccionando el elemento se ve que esta clase posee la regla `display: flex !important;`. La función `hide()` de **JQuery** lo que hace es darle al elemento un `display: none` en línea, por lo que la propiedad con el `!important` predomina por encima de esta, ocasionando que no puedas cambiar el `display` del elemento. Una solución sería quitarle esta clase y darle al elemento la tuya propia con un `display: flex` de esa manera la función `hide()` si que podría alterar el `display`.

Comment: A mi me funciona el code snippet sin problemas. Con `hide()` oculta el `div` y no lo vuelve a mostrar porque no es su finalidad. Si quieres mostrar/ocultar entonces tienes que usar `$('#comentarios').slideToggle();` como bien indica @Roy (hice una prueba y muestra/oculta tal cual esperas). Si usas otra librería tendrías que ponerla en el code snippet de tu pregunta para que podamos probar.

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de meter tu código en un snniped y de añadir las librerías de Bootstrap para que el error pueda reproducirse correctamente.

Comment: Bien visto @phpMyGuel, de hecho, si se le quita la clase `d-flex` funciona. Para mi es chocante que una librería del prestigio de Bootstrap haga uso de `!important`, cuando es un uso desaconsejado, precisamente por situaciones como estas.

Comment: @A.Cedano totalmente de acuerdo. Y me choca más aun que siendo una librería que va de la mano con **JQuery** no se haya previsto esta situación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que si ya estás utilizando bootstrap puedes recurrir a sus propio css y js para no enturbiar tu código y tirar de nuevos desarrollos para cosas en las que el framework se te quede corto o directamente no permita. Lo que quieres hacer en este caso con el botón es un toogle clarísimo, aspecto que resuelve bootstrap de manera más que eficiente con la clase css y desarrollo js "collapse", te dejo tanto el enlace a la documentación como un ejemplo que ellos mismo dan:

[enlace a documentación de bootstrap - collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>

</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Genial @JorgeGuz, muchas gracias!